# web with and with out "www"

Tags: php, apache2

I have a web sites on PhpFusion. When the page of the incoming from the link http://superparba.eu so everything is good. If I come from the link http://www.superparba.eu the wrong alignment and font will be loaded. The site code is identical in both cases. Where can the problem be?

Comment: Start by checking what the browser console has to tell you …

Comment: I try. Error: Access to font at 'http://superparba.eu/themes/SuperParba/opensans.ttf' from origin 'http://www.superparba.eu' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Bud i have in .htacess Header set Acess-Control-Allow-Origin "*". Bud still not works.

Answer (score 0):

'www' is technically a sub-domain of the superparba.eu domain. It *could* even point to a different IP address.

You may find that the assets; css files, images etc.. are not resolving the address correctly.

How are you connecting to these assets? via relative or absolute paths? Try using the absolute path and see if that helps.

If you have access to the DNS or a sysadmin, ask them to check that everything is configured to deliver assets regardless of the 'www' prefix.